# Unable to send email to multiple user

Tags: phpmailer

Right now I am doing a system. This system will send notification if educators have update a quiz. I want to send email to multiple user. I have refer this question 17860172 and Its solution but Its not works.

This is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE className='$classname'");

while ($rec= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$title = "Quiz Information";
$body = "Your quiz have been updated";
$email = $rec['stuEmail'];
}
include_once("mailer/mailer.php");
```

okey, for the mailer.php :

```
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "***";
$mail->Password = "***";
$mail->From     = "iii@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "i System";
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->Subject  = $title;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
if (file_exists($path)){
$mail->AddAttachment($path);
}
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->Send();
```

I want to send to all email in database based on className but when I click submit button the email doesn't send at all.

Comment: You're using an old version of PHPMailer, and have found some old rubbish code. I suggest you scrap it and start with a clean example of sending to a list, like [the example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Comment: Try to change from this `$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";` to `$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";` **AND** add this line `$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE className='$classname'");

while ($rec= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$title = "Quiz Information";
$body = "Your quiz have been updated";
$email = $rec['stuEmail'];

mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "***";
$mail->Password = "***";
$mail->From     = "iii@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "i System";
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->Subject  = $title;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
if (file_exists($path)){
$mail->AddAttachment($path);
}
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->Send();
}
```